# Android Retrofit Api ID

Tags: android, api, retrofit

Hello I have problem to use retrovite with get
My url is like this :

```
/infosRma?numRma=7978
```

I put in my Api Interface :

```
@GET("/infosRma/{id}/numRma")
Call<Rma> getRma(@Path("id") int id);
```

and this id numer in the activity

```
Call<Rma> rmaCall = apiInterface.getRma(79778);
    rmaCall.enqueue(new Callback<Rma>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<Rma> call, Response<Rma> response) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onResponse*************: " + response.body() );
                final Rma myResponse = response.body();

                txtName.setText(myResponse.getName());

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<Rma> call, Throwable t) {
                Log.e(TAG, "onFailure******************: " + t.getLocalizedMessage() );
            }
        });
```

But the connection doesn't work

```
No address associated with hostname
```

Do you have any idea

Kind

Comment: Try `@GET("/infosRma")`

`Call<Rma> getRma(@Query("numRma") int id)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The way you're passing the id, final URL will be

```
baseUrl/infosRma/7978/numRma
```

which would be incorrect. Use `Query` param instead of `Path` as follows:

```
@GET("/infosRma/")
Call<Rma> getRma(@Query("numRma") int id);
```

Comment: Hello thank you for your ansewer but I still have the same problem I put this :
  `  @GET("infosRma")
    Call<Rma> getRma(@Query("numRma") int id);`

Url is like this 
`infosRma?numRma=79778`
IS it ok for you ?
Sorry I new here

Comment: Maybe I didn't understand how it works ? For me in the base_url I put the http:// ....
 then `@GET("/infosRma")
    Call<Rma> getRma(@Query("numRma") int id);`
and `Call<Rma> rmaCall = apiInterface.getRma(85800);
        rmaCall.enqueue(new Callback<Rma>() {`

And on my response I can get the information ?
Maybe I miss something

Comment: Try to access the URL `baseUrl/infosRma?numRma=79778` in browser to see if you're getting the response.

Comment: I did it with insomnia every think is ok

Comment: Have you added internet permission in Manifest? and make sure the device you're testing on has internet access.